# App Engine Development Server encoding

Tags: google-app-engine, encoding

Is it possible to set UTF-8 encoding on dev-server? On the external (Google) server everything works fine, but on local server I'm getting "???????" instead of real characters in the Datastore Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

In GAE Python, to save utf-8 string in the datastore you need to do two thinks.

1/ Add headers on the top of your files:

The first one is for the convention, and the second one set by default all the content of your file in utf-8.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

2/ Decode your utf-8 string to save an unicode string in the datastore.

```
my_value="çéè!§ç!éàèàçèéàçè(à"
instance = mydatastore(mySavedUnicodeString=my_value.decode("utf-8"))
user_instance.put()
```